# Append strings to lines with looping over

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a file :

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

and another one:

```
111
222
333
444
.
.
999
```

My desired output after appending should be :

```
aaa 111
bbb 222 
ccc 333 
aaa 444
bbb 555
ccc 666
.
.
.
aaa nnn
```

I can append fixed strings with awk and sed, but I'm not able to figure out the looping over a fixed number of lines with different strings. While the second long file exists as a file, the strings to append don't have to be in a file, but since it is 11 lines of looping in the real case, I assume another file is the right ay to read them in.

Comment: Can we see the already-existing Source Lines of Code pertaining to the `awk` and `sed` Areas, @Rajib?

Comment: sed 's/^/"string"/g' appends to the beginning of each line. But that is not relevant in this instance. Which is why I refrained from putting it in the question. @DOBRESCU_Mihai

Comment: We understand that probably you want to write a nice _Bourne-Again_ Shell-Script, @Rajib. Can you start by writing a small algorithm in Pseudo-Code that describes what you want to achieve? That action could intensively clarify your Issue for everyone else who might be interested in solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed, bash, a function and two global variables (counter and f1).

```
counter=1
getnext() {
  f1=$(sed -n "${counter}p" file1)
  if [[ "$f1" == "" ]]; then
    counter=1
    f1=$(sed -n "${counter}p" file1)
  fi
  ((counter++))
}

while read -r f2; do getnext; echo "$f1 $f2"; done <file2
```

Output:

```
aaa 111
bbb 222
ccc 333
aaa 444
bbb 555
ccc 666
aaa 777
bbb 888
ccc 999
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out and let you know. Is file 1 the shorter "prepending" file?

Comment: yes, file1 is the shorter one.

Comment: this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with awk.
The prepending file (that goes to the first column) is loaded to the array `arr` at `BEGIN` section. The `-` (stdin) can be replaced by the file name.

The second file is the normal awk input.

```
echo -e 'a\nb\nc'|
awk 'BEGIN {
        while ((getline < "-") > 0) {
                arr[i++] = $0
        }
}

{
        if (j in arr) {
                print arr[j++], $0
                next
        }
        j = 0
        print arr[j++], $0
}' <(echo {1..10}|tr ' ' '\n')
```